# Add Custom Token RequestValidator to ASP.NET (not Core)

Tags: c#, .net, identityserver3

I would like to replace the default request token validator with a custom validator. The IdentityServer documentation for this indicates that the custom validator is registered in ASP.NET Core Startup.cs ConfigureServices(), but the application I'm working with is ASP.NET/.NET 4.5.

How can I register the custom validator in an ASP.NET application?

```
// My understanding is that this how I would add my validator with Core.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddCustomTokenRequestValidator<MyCustomRequestValidator>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very easy. In the `startup.cs` > `ConfigureService` You can specify which validator you want use. I use JWT authentication for a project code is following:

```
// Jwt Authentication
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
  {
       options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateActor = false,
        };
   });
```

Note: for this piece of code I used the library

`using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;`

I wish this helped. If you need further help you can add more details to your question I will help you.